# what does -alt |more command do in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash

can some one explain what does `-alt | more` command do in UNIX
with what is the function of `alt`,`-`, `|` and `more`.

Comment: Hi @Rahul, Wondering if you would like to accept my answer to your question?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have missed part of the command.

```
ls -alt | more
```

http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ls1.html

```
-a   : do not hide entries starting with .
-l   : use a long listing format.
-t   : sort by modification time.
|    : pipe the result to the next part of the command.
more : present the result one page at a time.
```